# Documentation generator for microservices protocol

Tags: java, documentation-generation

We are on the way to the microservices architecture. And now we faced with some problem. We want to have some tool that generate documentation for our protocol. It's not a REST based protocol, so we can't use any of tons already existing generators for web api. In other words we need something that takes our POJO with some annotations, comments, javadocs and generates HTML.

Comment: try Swagger. for reference output, see http://www.rei.com/rs-docs/